# Extjs 4 delete one row or few rows via one method

Tags: extjs, datagrid, extjs4

I have method on extjs that send selected items to server to delete them. Method on server getting List of objects.When i select in grid few rows this sending list but when i select one row this send object and method on server is not getting this. What can i do for delete one row or few rows via one method on server.

This is delete botton in extjs client:

```
click: {
                            scope: this,
                            fn: function (sm, selection) {
                                var selection = this.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection();                                
                                if (selection.length > 1) {                                                                           
                                        store.remove(selection); // here sending list of objects
                                        store.sync();                                                                                                           
                                }
                                else {
                                    store.remove(selection); // here sending object
                                    store.sync();
                                }                               
                              }
```

this is methode in server:

```
public JsonResult Delete(List<Customer> data);
```

Comment: In your writer, set allowSingle to false. See docs here:http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/?mobile=/api/Ext.data.writer.Json

Answer (score 0):

try with these code in else block when you selected only one row

```
                         else {

            var selected = this.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelected();                                

                            store.remove(selected ); // here sending object
                                store.sync();
                            }
```

Comment: i tryed this code:
else {                                    
  var selection =this.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection();       
                                        store.remove(selection);
                                        store.sync();                                    
                                }

Comment: Have you tried exactly what i have posted  (var selected = this.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelected(); ) there is difference between yours and mine, that is getSelected() and getSelection().If you select only one row then you can get that row using getSelected();. Could you please log the selected record before removing form the store and find the object is null or ot

Comment: var selected  - is undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
            function(){
            var sm=grid.getSelectionModel();
            var sel=sm.getSelections();
            for(i=0;i<sel.length;i++){
                grid.store.remove(sel[i]);
            }
```

This code may be help for you.